# Dropdownlist change function doesn't fire in Jquery dialog

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I need to update my second drop down list from database according to the value selected from first drop down list in the Jquery dialog.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnl" OnLoad="upnl_Load" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<div id="dv" style="display: none;" title="Tile">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Parent</td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDialog1" runat="server" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Child</td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDialog2" runat="server" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div >
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**JQuery**

```
function ShowDialog() {
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dv").dialog({
        draggable: true,
        modal: true,
        width: 500,
        height: 400
    });
});
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$("#<%= ddlDialog1.ClientID %>").change(function () {
   //This doesn't fire
    __doPostBack('<%= upnl.ClientID %>', "DialogOnChange");
});
});
```

Problem here is, 
How to change function doesn't fire when I select different values from first drop down list(ddlDialog1).

Any idea?

Comment: Can you verify the generated ID in the jQuery selector matches the ID of the dropdownlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$("#dv").dialog();` make your document changed.

you have to bind `$("#<%= ddlDialog1.ClientID %>")` after the dialog opened.

```
$("#dv").dialog({ 
  //...,
  open: function(){
    //..bind item in this dialog
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
$('#ddlDialog1').change(function(){            
        alert(Selected Value : + $('#ddlDialog1').val());    
});​
```